# No module named 'uff'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt, uff

**Goal :**
 To convert tensorflow .pb model to tensorrt

**System specs :** 
Ubundu 18.04
Cuda 10.0
TensorRT 5.1

Even Installed `sudo apt-get install uff-converter-tf`

Error obtained when trying to import `uff` in Python:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uff'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing `uff-converter-tf` is not enough, you will need to install Python UFF wheel to be able to use it. [Here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html) you will find complete installation guide.

If using Python 2.7:

```
pip2 install tensorrt-*-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

If using Python 3.x:

```
pip3 install tensorrt-*-cp3x-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

You will find these wheels with rest of TensorRT binaries that were resulted from unpacking `TensorRT-${version}.${os}.${arch}-gnu.${cuda}.${cudnn}.tar.gz`.

As always, it's best if installed in virtual environment.

Comment: I installed TensorRT through a .deb file. So, Where does my Uff wheel get stored ?

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas It doesn't. Download the tar.gz with appropriate version and take the wheel from there.